# Define callback functions to make values available outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my current jQuery onclick function for making an AJAX request to an external API, then displaying the results in a div. How would I implement a callback function that would allow the **response.vehicle** values to be available to another function that populates a separate div onclick further down the page?

```
$("#get-rego").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  ajaxLoader.style.display = "block";
  plate = document.getElementById("input_2_6").value;

  var requestData = $.post({
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: {
      "action": "get_vehicle",
      "plate": plate,
    },
    "dataType": "json"
  });

  requestData.done(function(obj) {
    var response = obj.idh;
    var vehicleMake,
        vehicleModel,
        vehicleYear,
        vehicleColour,
        vehicleSubModel,
        vehicleBodyStyle;

    ajaxLoader.style.display = "none";
    vehicleDetails.style.display = "block";
    vehicleMake = response.vehicle.make;
    vehicleModel = response.vehicle.model;
    vehicleYear = response.vehicle.year_of_manufacture;
    vehicleColour = response.vehicle.main_colour;
    vehicleSubModel = response.vehicle.submodel;
    vehicleBodyStyle = response.vehicle.body_style;

    vehicleDataSummaryOutput = "<div class=\"summary\">" +
      "<ul>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Make:</span> " + vehicleMake + "</li>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Model:</span> " + vehicleModel + "</li>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Year:</span> " + vehicleYear + "</li>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Colour:</span> " + vehicleColour + "</li>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Submodel:</span> " + vehicleSubModel + "</li>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Body Style:</span> " + vehicleBodyStyle + "</li>" +
      "</ul>" +
      "</div>";

    vehicleDataSummary.innerHTML = vehicleDataSummaryOutput;
  });

  requestData.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
  });
});
```

Comment: is their any error in console plz check

Comment: There are no errors. I am needing to figure out how to define a callback function to make the returned values available to other functions outside of the #get-rego click function.

Comment: function sample(use the vehicleDataSummaryOutput ){} out side the function and call sample(vehicleDataSummaryOutput ); thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        // Parse responseText
        var obj = JSON.parse(response.responseText);

        // Pass object to function
        doSomeThing(obj.vehicle);    
    }
});

function doSomeThing(vehicle)
{
 // Do some work ...
}
```